# NetMQ.FiniteStateMachineException: Rep.XRecv - cannot receive another request

Tags: c#, zeromq, netmq

I constantly get `NetMQ.FiniteStateMachineException`

sure, my code works... the exception does not occur right away... but over the course of a few hours, probably it will happen.

Does anyone know what is going on here to cause this exception?

I'm not really sure why, even though I did read the explanation here: [c# - ZeroMQ FiniteStateMachineException in REQ/REP pattern - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39860614/zeromq-finitestatemachineexception-in-req-rep-pattern/39868689#39868689)

I get a bunch of these:

### the exception

```
NetMQ.FiniteStateMachineException: Rep.XRecv - cannot receive another request
   at NetMQ.Core.Patterns.Rep.XRecv(Msg& msg)
   at NetMQ.Core.SocketBase.TryRecv(Msg& msg, TimeSpan timeout)
   at NetMQ.NetMQSocket.TryReceive(Msg& msg, TimeSpan timeout)
   at NetMQ.ReceivingSocketExtensions.ReceiveFrameString(IReceivingSocket socket, Encoding encoding, Boolean& more)
   at NinjaTrader.NinjaScript.AddOns.anAddOn.ZeroMQ_Server()
NetMQ.FiniteStateMachineException: Rep.XRecv - cannot receive another request
   at NetMQ.Core.Patterns.Rep.XRecv(Msg& msg)
   at NetMQ.Core.SocketBase.TryRecv(Msg& msg, TimeSpan timeout)
   at NetMQ.NetMQSocket.TryReceive(Msg& msg, TimeSpan timeout)
   at NetMQ.ReceivingSocketExtensions.ReceiveFrameString(IReceivingSocket socket, Encoding encoding, Boolean& more)
   at NinjaTrader.NinjaScript.AddOns.anAddOn.ZeroMQ_Server()
```

### my code

```cs
        // thread start code

                if (thread == null) {
                    print2("Addon {0}: is starting, listening on port: {1}...", GetType().Name, ZeroPort);
                    thread = new Thread(ZeroMQ_Server);
                    thread.Start();
                }

        // zeroMQ code

        #region TaskCallBack - NetMQ
        // This thread procedure performs the task.
        private void ZeroMQ_Server()
        { 
            bool quit = false;
            string bindAddress = "tcp://*:"+ZeroPort;
            try {
                while (!quit) {
                    try {
                        using (var repSocket = new ResponseSocket()) 
                        {
                            curRepSocket = repSocket;
                            print2("*** BINDING on {0} ***", bindAddress);
                            repSocket.Bind(bindAddress); 

                            while (!quit) {
                                try {
                                    Running = true;

                                    var msgStr = repSocket.ReceiveFrameString();
                                    print2("[►] {2} [REP:{0}] {1}", bindAddress, msgStr, DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss.fff"));
                                    if (processMsg(msgStr)) {
                                        StringBuilder csv = new StringBuilder();
                                        // string building stuff here

                                        string cs = csv.ToString();
                                        print2("[◄] csv: {0}", cs);
                                        repSocket.SendFrame(cs);
                                    } else {
                                        repSocket.SendFrame("Unrecognized Command: " + msgStr);
                                        break;
                                    }

                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                    quit = isThreadAborted(e);
                                }
                            }
                        }

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        if (e is AddressAlreadyInUseException) {
                            //print2("");
                        } else quit = isThreadAborted(e);
                    } finally {
                        curRepSocket = null;
                        Running = false;
                    }
                }
            } finally {
                //NetMQConfig.Cleanup(); 
            }
        }

        private bool isThreadAborted(Exception e) {
            if (e is ThreadAbortException) {
                print2("\n*** thread aborting... ***");
                return true;
            } else {
                print2(e);
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Response socket is a state machine, you must reply to each request.
From the code, it seems that if processMsg throws you don't send anything back, therefore you cannot receive again and get the exception.

It can also if Send failed if the client is gone.

Try to use router instead, like so:

```
while (true)
{
    bool more;
    var msg = routerSocket.ReceiveFrameBytes(out more);

    // Forwarding the routing id.
    routerSocket.SendMoreFrame(msg);

    // Bottom, next frame is the message
    if (msg.Length == 0)
        break;
}

// Write your handling here
```

Comment: if `processMsg()` returns `true` or `false` then `repSocket.SendFrame()` is still called... so that's where I'm confused. I know you can't see what is inside `processMsg()` but it has a `catch (Exception e)` that will return `false`, so either way it will return either `true` or `false` without allowing an `Exception` to escape - do you have any other ideas as to what I can look into?

Comment: any other exception?

Comment: I haven't seen one - however I did use to get `AddressAlreadyInUseException` s but I think I fixed that .. as a temporary workaround, can I just wrap the whole thing up in a catch block to prevent my program from stopping and create a new rep socket? if this `FiniteStateMachineException` is encountered?

Comment: You will have to re-create the response socket.

Comment: Actually, if the message is failed to sent (because the client is gone) it will fail as well.

Comment: You probably want to use router instead, I will update the answer with an example.

Comment: great, thanks - my clients do come and go sometimes. Oh also I have multiple clients communicating with one server, don't know if that makes a difference or not - by multiple I mean a few like 3 or 4

Comment: @somodron thx, I will update my code to use router and also keep my eyes out for more exceptions

Comment: so just to confirm my understanding from what you wrote and the docs on router-dealer, because they are asynchronous using router-dealer will completely sidestep this exception, and apart from being asynchronous the main difference is that there is a header on each message? since they are asynchronous, does that mean the will not block and timeout instead?

Comment: hi, forget the question about the timeout - I looked at the docs demo code and see a poller is used